Windows Native VPN client with Yubikey PIV intermittently fails client side EAP-TLS Fatal TLS Error 'access denied' and TLS handshake failure error 40
We have a really awkward issue with thw following
The setup looks like this:
Client Side

Windows 11 Client 23H2
Windows VPN Native Client using the below VPN configuration
Installed Yubikey Minidriver (tried without it, same thing)
Yubikey 5C NFC with Firmware 5.7.1

Server Side

Debian 12 Strongswan 5.9.8 with swanctl (config below; all
certificates valid and trusted)

We have two Windows Clients (same image), two Yubikeys and multiple issued certificates from the same CA. Some with 2048 Bit RSA keys some with 4096 (both are supported with yubikey firmware 5.7.1 and windows and are known to work as we can connect with both types sometimes)
The issue is completely random (to us) so stuff like below is happening:
Scenario A

User Certificate A is loaded on Yubikey A and used with client A to connect via IPSec -> Everything works fine; IPSec Connection is successful
Same Certificate A is loaded to Yubikey B and used with client B to connect -> Connection fails

Scenario B

User Certificate B (same CA other CN) is loaded on Yubikey B  and used with client B to connect -> connection successful
User Certificate B is loaded to Yubikey A and used with Client A to connection -> connection fails

Scenario C

User Certificate C (same CA other CN) is loaded on Yubikey A  and used with client A to connect -> connection fails
User Certificate C is loaded to Yubikey B and used with Client B to connection -> connection fails

The most awkward thing is this can change over time. On one day a configuration (e.g. certificate A loaded to yubikey A used on a client A) that previously hasn't been working might suddenly work even though it didn't before.
In strongswan this message pops up indicating the EAP-TLS client (windows device) reset the connection with a fatal tls alert. Up to that point the logs are identical to a working try:
Strongswan log
2024-12-09T10:35:22.392364+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: 05[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 7 [ EAP/RES/TLS ]
2024-12-09T10:35:22.392440+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: 05[TLS] EAP_TLS payload => 17 bytes @ 0x7f704c05d8a0
2024-12-09T10:35:22.392494+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: 05[TLS]    0: 02 D4 00 11 0D 80 00 00 00 07 15 03 03 00 02 02  ................
2024-12-09T10:35:22.392546+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: 05[TLS]   16: 31                                               1
2024-12-09T10:35:22.392625+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: 05[TLS] processing TLS Alert record (2 bytes)
2024-12-09T10:35:22.392700+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: 05[TLS] received fatal TLS alert 'access denied'
2024-12-09T10:35:22.392765+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: 05[IKE] EAP method EAP_TLS failed for peer 192.168.30.114
2024-12-09T10:35:22.392841+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: 05[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 7 [ EAP/FAIL ]
2024-12-09T10:35:22.392908+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: 05[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.30.116[4500] to 192.168.30.1[64917] (88 bytes)
2024-12-09T10:35:22.392985+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: 05[IKE] IKE_SA eap-tls[9078] state change: CONNECTING => DESTROYING
2024-12-09T10:35:22.393082+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: received packet: from 192.168.30.1[64917] to 192.168.30.116[4500] (104 bytes)
2024-12-09T10:35:22.393214+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: parsed IKE_AUTH request 7 [ EAP/RES/TLS ]
2024-12-09T10:35:22.393292+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: received fatal TLS alert 'access denied'
2024-12-09T10:35:22.393403+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: EAP method EAP_TLS failed for peer 192.168.30.114
2024-12-09T10:35:22.393491+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: generating IKE_AUTH response 7 [ EAP/FAIL ]
2024-12-09T10:35:22.393580+01:00 debian charon-systemd[15870]: sending packet: from 192.168.30.116[4500] to 192.168.30.1[64917] (88 bytes)

Windows SCHANNEL logs
SCHANNEL logs show how Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider is used but the process fails.
Information 12/9/2024 10:45:18 Schannel 36867 None
A TLS client credential is being created.
the SSPI client process svchost[EapHost] (PID: 5776).
Information 12/9/2024 10:45:18 Schannel 36868 None
The TLS client credential private key has the following properties:
CSP name: Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider
CSP type: 1
Key name: 7d6ba0cb-8ab2-36e4-325b-bf23475fc105
Key type: key exchange
Key identifier: 0x0
The attached data contains the certificate.
Information 12/9/2024 10:45:18 Schannel 36888 None 

A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. 
This may cause the connection to be terminated. 
The fatal alert defined by the TLS protocol has the following code: 40. 

Target name:
The SSPI client process is svchost[EapHost] (PID: 5776).
The TLS alert registry is located at: http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-6

Which is awkward because when the connection is sucessful schannel log is showing that instead of "Microsoft Base SmartCard Crypto Provider" the "Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider" is used like this:
Information 12/9/2024 10:45:18 Schannel 36867 None
A TLS client credential is being created.
the SSPI client process svchost[EapHost] (PID: 5776).
Information 12/9/2024 10:48:44 Schannel 36868 None
The TLS client credential private key has the following properties:
CSP name: Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider
CSP type: 0
Key name: 72c27e3d-737e-301e-c312-23a1ef5fc105
Key type: N/A
Key flag: 0x0
The attached data contains the certificate.
Information 12/9/2024 10:48:46 AM Schannel 36880 None
A client handshake for TLS was successfully performed. The cryptographic parameters negotiated are:
Protocol version: TLS 1.2
CipherSuite: 0xC030
Exchange strength: 384 bits
Context handle: 0x1defdf9c800
Target name:
Local certificate subject name: CN=######
Remote certificate subject name: CN=#######

We don't know what this random behaviour is caused by, and hoped you guys can help us out. There's nothing indicating the yubikey or strongswan server are doing something wrong instead Microsoft seems to randomly decide when it really sends out the private key using the key storage provider properly.
Thank you in advance for any kind of help.
VPN Settings Windows
Name                  : test
ServerAddress         : #########
AllUserConnection     : False
Guid                  : {4E1CF7BC-B9B7-42BC-AC55-159E3143806E}
TunnelType            : Ikev2
AuthenticationMethod  : {Eap}
EncryptionLevel       : Custom
L2tpIPsecAuth         :
UseWinlogonCredential : False
EapConfigXmlStream    : #document
ConnectionStatus      : Disconnected
RememberCredential    : False
SplitTunneling        : True
DnsSuffix             :
IdleDisconnectSeconds : 0
AuthenticationTransformConstants : SHA256128
CipherTransformConstants         : AES256
DHGroup                          : ECP384
IntegrityCheckMethod             : SHA384
PfsGroup                         : ECP384
EncryptionMethod                 : AES256

Strongswan
connections {
  eap-tls {
    pools = ipv4
    local {
      auth = pubkey
      certs = servercert.pem
      id = ###############
    }
    remote {
      auth = eap-tls
      cacerts = cacertificate.pem
      eap_id = %any
    }
    children {
      eap-tls {
        local_ts = 0.0.0.0/0
        esp_proposals = aes256-sha256
       }
    }
  }
}
pools {
  ipv4 {
    addrs = 10.10.1.64/26
  }
}


If an error or failure can be repeated, that is not random. Random would be if it worked on B most of the time, but sometimes did not.

@greg-askew Probably didnt find the right words for this. Certificate A on yubikey A and client A might be working for a day and then suddenly stop working the next day. Also while not working on client A the same certificate on a different yubikey might work on client B and vice versa.
What i call random here is not that on 10 tries 5 go through and 5 do not, but the fact that there is seemingly nothing different in 2 setups but one client/yubikey combo works and the other does not or the other way around.
